# FirePHP not outputting anything

Tags: php, logging, firephp

I have been trying to get FirePHP to work for an hour now. I have the latest firebug installed and it works fine. I also installed the FirePHP addon. Then I downloaded the library files and included them in my php file. I am sure that they are being included. Now I started FirePHP with the `ob_start();` statement. Then I tried logging something with `fb('Log message', FirePHP::LOG);` but nothing showed up on the console. I have tried looking in the Net Panel, The Console window, had All checked, tried using the OOP method, etc. but nothing is working. I can see headers being sent just fine but I cannot see any logged messages. What gives?

Comment: What versions of each are you using?  For a while, only the latest RC of the next version actually worked with modern Firebug versions.  I'm not sure if they fixed this yet.

Comment: Restarting Firefox is sometimes necessary.

Comment: Any luck with this? I've been having the same problems.  I can even get the header already sent error, but I still can't manage to see anything in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had the same problem a number of times. One of the following 'fixes' worked for me in the past.

- Mismatch between server lib and client plugin, that is my fault.
- Newer version of firebug being installed and not compatible with firephp plugin
- Restarting firefox
- Making sure that both the console and net tabs are enabled.
- Look at the headers being sent in the inspector, make sure there are headers like X-Wf-1-1-1-2

Comment: `Making sure that both the console and net tabs are enabled` was the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Installed everything as mentionned in the installation walkthrough.

I was using Symfony 2.2. First, you must know that when using the file there is a Symfony plugin that can be found at : http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFirePHPPlugin

look at the readme to know how to install it.

Second, I also had a problem with Monolog's FirePHP handler in my config where it was bugging FirePHP Add-On in Firefox thus preventing the information from showing. I used the configuration where all the Info level errors were sent to FirePHP in config_dev file. Once removed from the configs, the previous FirePHP events started showing in the FirePHP Add-On on Firefox.

Hope this helps a couple of you guys :)